Linux c mutex memory errors and leak
I define a pthread_mutex_t in a shared object library, initialize it in a process and use it in a function of the library. Following the structure of the code. With processes I mean separated running binaries. Consider that multiple threads are started, that run function_thread.
I use systat and sa to profile the resources usage and noted that the memory used by process2 constantly increase, like there is a memory leak.
Then I run process2 with Valgrind, and I report the output. If I remove the pthread_mutex the errors disappear. The word futex in the error messages suggests me that they are caused by the mutex. Am I doing something wrong in the code? Does it make sense to declare a variable in a shared library and then use it in the threads of a different binaries?
lib.c:
pthread_mutex_t xwebwd_mutex;

int function_foo() {
...
  if (pthread_mutex_trylock(&xwebwd_mutex) == 0) {
    <do something>
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&xwebwd_mutex);
  }
...
}

process1.c:
extern pthread_mutex_t xwebwd_mutex;

int main() {
...
  pthread_mutex_init(&xwebwd_mutex, NULL);
...
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&xwebwd_mutex);
  return 0;
}

process2.c:
...
function_thread() {
  function_foo();
}
...

==4581== Invalid read of size 4
==4581==    at 0x4BDDA18: g_cond_signal (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.7200.3)
==4581==  Address 0x5d7d90c is 36 bytes inside a block of size 124 free'd
==4581==    at 0x4867E54: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==4581==  Block was alloc'd at
==4581==    at 0x486AAA8: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==4581== 
==4581== Invalid write of size 4
==4581==    at 0x4BDDA20: g_cond_signal (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.7200.3)
==4581==  Address 0x5d7d90c is 36 bytes inside a block of size 124 free'd
==4581==    at 0x4867E54: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==4581==  Block was alloc'd at
==4581==    at 0x486AAA8: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==4581== 
==4581== Syscall param futex(futex) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==4581==    at 0x50B0EC0: syscall (in /lib/libc.so.6)
==4581==    by 0x4BDDA47: g_cond_signal (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.7200.3)
==4581==  Address 0x5d7d90c is 36 bytes inside a block of size 124 free'd
==4581==    at 0x4867E54: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==4581==  Block was alloc'd at
==4581==    at 0x486AAA8: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==4581== 
==4581== 
==4581== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4581==     in use at exit: 38,235 bytes in 359 blocks
==4581==   total heap usage: 115,927 allocs, 115,568 frees, 23,682,340 bytes allocated
==4581== 
==4581== Searching for pointers to 338 not-freed blocks
==4581== Checked 8,776,812 bytes
==4581== 
==4581== Thread 1:
==4581== 160 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 6
==4581==    at 0x486AAA8: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==4581== 
==4581== 584 bytes in 56 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 6
==4581==    at 0x4864CB8: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==4581== 
==4581== 1,008 bytes in 21 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 6
==4581==    at 0x4C8D7F0: type_node_any_new_W (in /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.7200.3)
==4581== 
==4581== 9,613 bytes in 21 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 6
==4581==    at 0x486ADA8: realloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==4581== 
==4581== 10,400 bytes in 151 blocks are still reachable in loss record 5 of 6
==4581==    at 0x486AAA8: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==4581== 
==4581== 15,378 bytes in 88 blocks are still reachable in loss record 6 of 6
==4581==    at 0x4864DE4: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==4581== 
==4581== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4581==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4581==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4581==      possibly lost: 160 bytes in 1 blocks
==4581==    still reachable: 36,983 bytes in 337 blocks
==4581==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4581== 
==4581== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==4581== 
==4581== 1 errors in context 1 of 4:
==4581== Thread 2 dbus8528695976:
==4581== Syscall param futex(futex) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==4581==    at 0x50B0EC0: syscall (in /lib/libc.so.6)
==4581==    by 0x4BDDA47: g_cond_signal (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.7200.3)
==4581==  Address 0x5d7d90c is 36 bytes inside a block of size 124 free'd
==4581==    at 0x4867E54: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==4581==  Block was alloc'd at
==4581==    at 0x486AAA8: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==4581== 
==4581== 
==4581== 2 errors in context 2 of 4:
==4581== Invalid write of size 4
==4581==    at 0x4BDDA20: g_cond_signal (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.7200.3)
==4581==  Address 0x5d7d90c is 36 bytes inside a block of size 124 free'd
==4581==    at 0x4867E54: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==4581==  Block was alloc'd at
==4581==    at 0x486AAA8: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==4581== 
==4581== 
==4581== 2 errors in context 3 of 4:
==4581== Invalid read of size 4
==4581==    at 0x4BDDA18: g_cond_signal (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.7200.3)
==4581==  Address 0x5d7d90c is 36 bytes inside a block of size 124 free'd
==4581==    at 0x4867E54: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==4581==  Block was alloc'd at
==4581==    at 0x486AAA8: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==4581== 
==4581== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)


The variable is not shared.

By the way, the term “shared library” doesn’t mean that the library’s resources are shared amongst every process - only that the code itself might be shared (reducing the system’s memory usage).

Ignore the leaks until you've fixed the other errors.

@nneonneo I'm not sure if it's the case but the read-only ELF sections could also be shared.

arm isn't that well supported. What OS, CPU, compiler and Valgrind version are you using?

@PaulFloyd ah yes, read-only data can also be shared. The writable data sections, too, subject to the constraint that if they're ever modified, they'll be unshared (technically, this can achieved by mapping writable file segments in as COW memory).
